# Django UpdateWithInlinesView not saving deleted inlines

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a jQuery plugin (by elo80ka) for adding and deleting inlines from Template.
The issue I have is when I'm adding new data all goes well and data gets saved. But once I try to remove existing ones I get a redirect without deleted objects. (once I hit remove, the inline gets removed, I've checked via Inspector)

```
class PlaceUpdateInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = AdditionalLoadingPlace
    form_class = AdditionalLoadingPlaceInlineFormSet
    factory_kwargs = {'extra': 0, 'max_num': 5,
                    'can_order': False, 'can_delete': True}

class PlaceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateWithInlinesView):
    model = Place
    form_class = PlaceCreateForm
    inlines = [PlaceUpdateInline]

    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        form.save(commit=True)

        for inline in inlines:
            objects = inline.save(commit=False)
            for obj in inline.deleted_objects:
                # never called
                obj.delete()
            for object in objects:
                if object.place:
                    object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

EDIT:

So, my template has this custom rendering of each field:

```
{{ inlines.0.management_form }}
{{ inlines.0.non_form_errors }}
{% for form in inlines.0 %}
    <div class="inline {{ inlines.0.prefix }}">
        {{ form.hidden_field.as_hidden }} 
        {{ form.place.errors }}
        {{ form.place }}
        {{ form.id }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But delete works if I do that like this:

```
{{ inlines.0.management_form }}
{{ inlines.0.non_form_errors }}
{% for form in inlines.0 %}
    <div class="inline {{ inlines.0.prefix }}">
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

There seems to be an issue with my hidden fields (which I update with jQuery latter on, and I don't want to show it to users)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway it seems I was missing something in my template and it wasn't rendering correctly (I guess). So I ended up doing this:

```
{% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

And also had my fields hidden from forms:

```
class PlaceInlineFormSet(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AdditionalLoadingPlace
        fields = ('hidden_field', 'place')

        widgets = {
            'place' : forms.TextInput(),
            'hidden_field': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```